# Send Telemetry Data to Azure IoT Central Device using HTTP GET Requests

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-central

I'm trying to send telemetry to a device in Azure Iot Central, with HTTP GET requests.

I have a legacy iot application, and I am trying to migrate it to Azure IoT Central, so for now I need to synchronize my ongoing Iot Data to Azure IoT Central.

One way I found to do it quickly was to use Logic Apps.

I have successfully created the Iot Central application and Logic Apps configuration, and I also found a way to get device information and update properties, but I'm not finding where to send telemetry data.

Is it possible to do with Logic Apps, or there is another way to send the telemetry?

Any hints will be very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you should use the [REST POST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/senddeviceevent) request to send a telemetry data to the IoT Central App.

The following is an example for *device1*:

[image]

Note, that the *iothubhostname* must be obtained from [DPS service](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/rest/api/iot-dps/runtimeregistration/registerdevice) and also the *Authorization* header ([sas token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security)) is required.

and the following screen snippet shows the IoT Central App Dashboard:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I don't find anywhere in Azure IoT Central to get this "fully qualified iot hub name", could you point me some directions ...

Comment: Have a look at my answer in the https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68634dbb-0bd3-4ea1-8836-844554338824/is-there-a-way-to-get-iot-hub-host-name-underneath-iot-central-from-rest-api?forum=azureiothub